# Failed with: Uncaught Tried to save an object with a pointer to a new, unsaved object

Tags: javascript, cloud, parse-platform

I am having this error, and this is my cloud code.

```
var HighScore = Parse.Object.extend("HighScore");
highScore = new HighScore();
highScore.set("totalXp", request.params.totalXp);
highScore.set("regionId", request.params.regionId);

var relation = highScore.relation("userId");
relation.add(request.user);

highScore.save();

response.success(highScore);
```

The response returned empty, but weird thing is, the relation is added successfully when I look at the data browser.

Can't find solid answer or explanation. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I referred to [here](https://www.parse.com/questions/adding-objects-to-relation-error-you-cant-add-an-unsaved-parseobject-to-a-relation), and modified my code to it. The reason is because I put creating object and adding relation in 1 save() operation.

```
var HighScore = Parse.Object.extend("HighScore");
highScore = new HighScore();
highScore.set("totalXp", request.params.totalXp);
highScore.set("regionId", request.params.regionId);

highScore.save(null, {
    success: function(savedHighScore){
            var relation = savedHighScore.relation("userId");
            relation.add(request.user);
            //relation.add(Parse.User.current());
        savedHighScore.save(null, {
            success: function(finalHighScore){
                response.success(finalHighScore);
            },
            error: function(finalHighScore, error){
            }
        });
    },
    error: function(highScore, error){
        console.log("failed to create");
    }
});
```