# Using CloudCode to add data to existing attribute causes error

Tags: javascript, ios, parse-platform

For each `User` object, I have an attribute called "trueFriends" where it contains an array of `userIds`. I would like to modify an user's list of "trueFriends" every time a friend is added, and am using the following Cloud Code function:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('editUser', function(request, response) {
    var userId = request.params.userId,
        trueFriends = request.params.trueFriends;

    var User = Parse.Object.extend('_User'),
        user = new User({ objectId: userId });

    user.add('trueFriends', trueFriends); //<-- If I change to "true_friends", this code works

    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    user.save().then(function(user) {
        response.success(user);
    }, function(error) {
        response.error(error)
    });
});
```

I then call the function normally from my iOS app:

```
[PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"editUser" withParameters:
          @{@"userId": userToAdd.objectId,
            @"trueFriends": self.currentUser.username}
            block:^(id object, NSError *error) {
            }];
```

However, I get the error "Uncaught Tried to save an object with a pointer to a new, unsaved object." As per the comment in the Cloud code, if I change the code from "trueFriends" to "true_friends", it then no longer gives this error and everything saves successfully. I am unsure how to resolve the situation, despite looking at [similar](https://parse.com/questions/failed-with-uncaught-tried-to-save-an-object-with-a-pointer-to-a-new-unsaved-object) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16514079/failed-with-uncaught-tried-to-save-an-object-with-a-pointer-to-a-new-unsaved-o) - thanks for the help!

Comment: in your Parse.com _User class is the column name true_Friends or trueFriends

Comment: In Parse.com, the column name is `trueFriends`